# How can I make KDE and other non-GNOME apps inherit the Ubuntu theme?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, kde, themes, qt

I'm running Ubuntu (9.04) and have a bunch of different types of apps installed on my system:

- GNOME apps like Firefox, gEdit.
- KDE4 apps like AmaroK and KATE.
- Qt apps like VLC.
- Opera browser, which uses Qt for OS widgets but looks different to VLC.

Basically I'd like everything to resemble whatever my current Ubuntu theme is - at the moment it's "Dust Sand" but I do change it occasionally. Is this possible?

GNOME apps are obviously fine. I've found the `qtconfig` which has a "GTK+" setting that works for VLC. The main two things are KDE4 and Opera. There appears to be a `kde4-config` app on my system but running it doesn't do anything. I remember running a KDE config on an older Ubuntu version, that was for KDE3. I could change colours and buttons but IIRC there were some things that still didn't look 100% right.

In Opera I'm talking about the menus mainly (and right click). Save/Open dialogs use GNOME, and Opera has its own skin (plus "Windows native" which is totally fugly, maybe that's inheriting the Qt options). I use the version from Opera's repos: `http://deb.opera.com/opera/ sid`. Under "About Opera" is:

```
System          i686, 2.6.28-15-generic
Qt library      3.3.8b
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [**QGtkStyle**](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Styles/GtkStyle), a project to [create a GTK+ layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QGtkStyle) for Qt-based applications (like KDE) running on GTK2-based desktops (like Gnome).

There are other ideas and scripts in the discussion on this topic at Ubuntu Brainstorm: [Idea #1744: GNOME themes should affect Qt themes](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/1744/), and more of them in this discussion [Idea #1714: GNOME QT integration](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/1714/) (and the numerous duplicate ideas gathered under this question).

One of the noteworthy attempts is [**UniformUI**](http://andrealazzarotto.com/2009/06/14/uniformui-is-the-definitive-way-to-integrate-qt-and-kde-apps-in-the-gnome-desktop/), which attempts to automate configuration of Qt settings to match the current Gtk+ style, partially using [**QtCurve**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QtCurve) and [**QGtkStyle**](http://labs.trolltech.com/page/Projects/Styles/GtkStyle) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a way to get exactly what you want, but you can coerce both gnome & kde into using Qt by using QtCurve. Try `sudo apt-get install qtcurve-kde4`

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to Opera, but you might want to try the qt4-linked version of Opera rather than the qt3 version the deb.opera.com repository provides. The qt4 version looks a bit better (the menus and widgets in particular), and thus not quite as out-of-place in a GNOME environment as the qt3 version.

To get a hold of this version of Opera you actually have to do a bit of digging in their [FTP server](ftp://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1000/final/en/), but at least they provide .deb packages both for [i386 (32-bit)](ftp://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1000/final/en/i386/opera_10.00.4585.gcc4.qt4_i386.deb) and [x86_64 (64-bit)](ftp://ftp.opera.com/pub/opera/linux/1000/final/en/x86_64/opera_10.00.4585.gcc4.qt4_amd64.deb) for your convenience.

Comment: Ooh thanks, that's sorted Opera. Hopefully they'll add the qt4 version to the repos soon, I prefer having software updating automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a program called "Qt 4 settings" in the `System>Preferences`  menu.
From there you can change the theme that all qt4 apps use, which might solve your problem.

Comment: The app I mentioned in my question, `qtconfig` is the same as you describe here. Changing styles here only affects VLC though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to make Qt3 look like GTK+, but Qt4 can mimic GTK+ more or less perfectly. The only difference will be the inherent design differences between Qt (or KDE) apps and GTK+ (or GNOME) ones: file chooser dialogs, for instance.

Different Qt-based applications look in different places for their appearance settings. KDE4 applications look in the KDE config, which can be edited using the KDE4 systemsettings program. Non-KDE Qt apps look in the regular Qt configuration, which can be edited by qtconfig (the Qt4 version). I'm not sure if Opera is special and does its own thing, but is has to store its config *somewhere*, so it must be possible to copy (or symlink) your standard Qt4 config to that somewhere in order to make Opera fall in line.

Answer (score 0):

kwriteconfig --file kdeglobals --group General --key widgetStyle gtk